# How can I execute multiple expressions using the -exec option in Linux via the find command?

Tags: linux, find

I did have a read of the post at [How do I execute multiple commands when using find?](https://superuser.com/questions/236601/how-do-i-execute-multiple-commands-when-using-find). Unless I have misunderstood the answer provided, I do not believe it provides the solution I am seeking.

My requirement is to find a specific set of files. If found to then create a directory. If the directory has been successfully created only then to extract the files. Once extracted to delete the source files. How would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you use `-exec` to call a script doing the complicated things?

Comment: @Nifle - Couldn't I just look for a success status code using `-exec` e.g. if 0 then do something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you post gives the "correct" answer, in my opinion. Just spawn a shell. Without doing this, you'll not have a large enough toolbox. You *could* construct a find command in pseudocode such as:

```
find /path -criteria -exec mkdir {} \; -exec extract {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

This will stop on any error, as predicates are naturally and'ed together. But, it gives you insufficient control over the naming of the directory. It's guaranteed to fail.

Spawning a shell resolves this as you'll have the whole shell language at your grasp:

```
find /path -criteria -exec /bin/sh '
    for d; do
        mkdir "${d##*/}" && tar xvf "$d" && rm "$d"
    done' _ {} +
```

Note that this version has the side effect of continuing on an error for any given iteration of the loop -- it spawns a single shell for *all* results. I'd suggest spawning the shell with the -e flag if you want to stop hard on any error.

Comment: Can I ask what the magic _ and + symbols at the end mean?

Comment: @stib: The underscore is the argv[0] to the /bin/sh process. It's meaningless (it could be anything you want). The "{} +" is find syntax for "append all the results as arguments to the -exec program" -- argv[1]..argv[n]. It spawns a single process for all results, rather than spawning individual processes for each result, as you would get by using "{} \;".