# Showing filenames when grepping from mysqlbinlog

Tags: mysql, grep

I am trying to find out when some queries have been executed on our DB. For that I started looking in MySql binarylogs, using `mysqlbinlog`:

```
find -name "binlog.000056*" -exec mysqlbinlog {} \; | grep -i "update .* my_special_column=value"
```

The problem is that this way I cannot find out in which file it finds results, as grep gets the input from its input (through pipe) and not from a direct file.

I thought using `tee`, but did not succeed.

So the question: how to use `find -exec mysqlbinlog...` and `grep,` showing also the filename where grep finds the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are comments and timestamps that appear above each SQL command.

When you run the grep, [use the -A, -B, or -C option](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_grep.htm).

What that does is the following

- `-A` shows you a number of lines after the pattern is found
- `-B` shows you a number of lines before the pattern is found
- `-C` shows you a number of lines before and after the pattern is found

For example, run the grep like this to include 2 lines above the matching pattern

```
find -name "binlog.000056*" -exec mysqlbinlog {} \; | grep -i -B 2 "update .* my_special_column=value"
```

If you want the iterate through the names and see the filename, do this

```
for X in `ls binlog.000056*` ; do echo ${X} ; mysqlbinlog ${X} | grep -i -B 2 "update .* my_special_column=value" ; done
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Although I was thinking there is a solution with pipes only your solution works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run multiple commands in exec. Have a look to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/236601/how-do-i-execute-multiple-commands-when-using-find) and the different answers.