# How do I pass combined commands to 'find -exec'?

Tags: bash, find

**What is valid syntax to pass combined commands to `find` with the `-exec` option?**

---

**Example:**

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep FirstKeyWord {} | grep SecondKeyWord \;
```

fails with the following error message:

```
find: grep: missing argument to `-exec`
;: No such file or directory
```

There is the same kind of failure when commands are combined using `&&` or `;` instead of `|`. I even tried quoting the combined commands with ' or with $() or {} or such, but it (miserably) failed.

Note: I'm looking for a one-liner solution, without using custom scripts.

Comment: In the Stack Overflow community, there is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119946/find-exec-with-multiple-commands

Comment: In the Super User community, another similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/236601/how-do-i-execute-multiple-commands-when-using-find

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a complex shell command in the argument to exec by explicitly invoking a shell there.

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'grep FirstKeyWord "$1" | grep SecondKeyWord' -- {} \;
```

This executes `sh` with the provided command list for each file, passing the filename in `$1`.

EDIT: The OP points out that this works and is simpler:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'grep FirstKeyWord {} | grep SecondKeyWord' \;
```

Comment: The first solution is safe, but the second creates a code injection vulnerability ([see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010)). Relevant in serverside scripts.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example, you can do this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep FirstKeyWord {} \; | grep "SecondKeyWord"
```

BTW, this can also be done without using a second grep.  Instead, use `egrep` with the two alternatives of `FirstKeyWord` followed by `SecondKeyWord` or `SecondKeyWord` followed by `FirstKeyWord`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec egrep "FirstKeyWord.*SecondKeyWord|SecondKeyWord.*FirstKeyWord" {} \;
```

If you can make some guarantees about the resulting pathnames from the `find` (like no leading or internal spaces and no newlines in the pathnames), you can also do it this way:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print | while read filename; do grep "FirstKeyWord" "${filename}" | grep "SecondKeyWord"; done
```

The more general answer is "you can't" directly from `find`.  Piping commands or using `&&` or `||` is a function of the shell, not a function of executing processes.

I have used this pattern before, but it is fragile and more complex:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print \
    | sed -e 's;[\\$"`!];\\&;g' \
          -e 's;^.*$;grep "FirstKeyWord" "&" | grep "SecondKeyWord";' \
    | sh
```

Print out each filename, use `sed` to transform it into a shell script on the fly (being careful to escape the characters in the filename that might cause problems when enclosed in shell double-quotes), then run the result through the shell.

The other solution is to create a shell script that does your processing and call that shell script from find:

```
$ cat grepit.sh
#!/bin/sh
grep "FirstKeyWord" "$1" | grep "SecondKeyWord"
$ find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh grepit.sh {} \;
```

Comment: In your example answer, if the file name contains "SecondKeyWord" but not the contents of the file, the line will be kept whereas it should be filtered out.

Comment: I really need the second command to be *combined*  to the first command so that they become one and single -exec parameter.

Comment: This is only a workaround for the specific example. I'd like to know how to pass complex (=combined) commands to find -exec, not just to use the example from the question.

Comment: Edited to answer the general question:  You can't; not directly from `find`.

Answer (score 0):

The use of "-exec" is highly discouraged, because it creates a lot of sub-process.

Please consider using "find" with "xargs", (using "-print0" and "-0")

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 grep FirstKeyWord | grep SecondKeyWord
```

With this, "grep" is spawned once for many files (up to the limit of the number of arguments a program can have).

Comment: Using `xargs` is a good idea for the example, but the question is about `find` with `-exec`. BTW, can you share a reference website where it is explained why using "-exec" would be "highly discouraged" (maybe an exaggeration)?

Comment: Just test the difference by yourself. I have 407 shell scripts in several directories. 17 seconds for : find '*.sh' -exec grep '^#' '{}' ';' ### but 3 seconds for find '*.sh' -print0 | xargs -0 grep '#^'

Comment: Exec with + instead of \; to handle multiple parameters performs similarly to xargs; there's no need to conflate the use of exec in the general case with a proliferation of sub-processes.